# How to get 4 digits from the middle a string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string variable like test10015, i want to get just the 4 digits 1001,
what is the best way to do it?
i"m working in asp.net c#

Comment: All the answers proposed so far assume the digits will be in a certain position within the string, and would break if the string was instead something like `"a1234b"`. Please provide more a specific explanation on *exactly* what kinds of inputs you expect and what output you would like. Also, please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thank you, but my digits are in a certain position.

Comment: try this. it will work for you:

    string s = "test10015";
    string newstring = s.Substring(s.Length - 5, 4);
    Console.WriteLine(newstring);

Answer (score 2):

With Linq:

```
var expected = str.Skip(4).Take(4);
```

Without Linq:

```
var expected = str.Substring(4,4);
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey As an alternative, not really required.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "test10015";
string result = input.Substring(4, 4);
```

Comment: This is wrong.  The first parameter is the position in the original string, which you've set as the first character.

Answer (score 0):

Select the first four digits in your string:

```
string str = "test10015";
string strNum = new string(str.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).Take(4).ToArray());
```

Comment: @RobertHarvey well do you have a solution that isn't Linq?

Comment: Absolutely.  Substring()

Comment: Well then instead of criticizing everyone else, it maybe more productive if you provided your own solution.

Comment: Or a regular expression. (just for the sake of argument)

Comment: substring is good for this spec. case.. I guess he wanted something more generic..but that's just a guess..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can subtract 5 from from the length to start from your required index. Make sure the format of string remains the same.

```
string res = str.Substring(str.Length-5, 4);
```